# Intersection of Hilbert spaces with Schauder basis

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let

- $H$ be a infinite dimensional, separable, complex Hilbert space,
- $\{v_{1_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $H$,
- $V_1=\operatorname{span}\{v_{1_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$
- $U_1=\overline{V_1}$.

We know that $\{v_{1_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Schauder basis of $U_1$

Let $\{v2_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $H$. Furthermore let,

- $V_2=\operatorname{span}\{v_{1_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$,
- $U_2=\overline{V_2}$.

We know that $\{v_{2_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Schauder basis of $U_2$ and furthermore, we know that $V_1 \cap V_2 = \{0\}$.

**The question**: Is it true that $U_1 \cap U_2 = \{0\}$.

Comment: If someone edits this question again, I would suggest the notation $v_{1,n}$. Also the definition of $V_2$ uses the $v_1$'s rather than the $v_2$'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the intersection of the $U$'s might even be full. Note that it suffices to find $V$'s of countable dimension, since we can then use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm to find an orthonormal basis, which will be automatically Schauder.

Set $H=L^2([0,1])$, $V_1$ the space generated by the $\mathbb1_{[k/n,(k+1)/n)}$, and $V_2$ that of the polynomials. They are dense, so the corresponding $U$'s are equal (they are precisely $H$). The intersection of the $V$'s is precisely the constants, but you can get rid of them by considering $H'\subset H$ the functions of zero mean, and $V'_i=V_i$.

For an explicit example of sequences, consider the basis of Haar wavelets in $H'$ and that of the non-constant Legendre polynomials.

Comment: Thanks so much Pierre for your answer.

Comment: But is the $x^n$ sequence a Schauder basis of its closed span?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Actually, this point is not clear. he did not mention if they are Schauder basis

Comment: @PierrePC so your answer is invalid in my context?

Comment: @PierrePC ok thanks in any case

Comment: MateyMath:  @PierrePC's argument works much more generally. Take **any** two dense subspaces $V_1$, $V_2$ in $H$ which have zero intersection: then one can use Gram-Schmidt to construct orthonormal subsets $(v_{1,n})_{n\geq 1} \subset V_1$ and $(v_{2,n})_{n \geq 1} \subset V_2$ which have dense linear span, and hence are ONB for $H=\overline{V_1}=\overline{V_2}$

Comment: @YemonChoi you are right